# DCOS connection refused on marathon-lb

Tags: containers, mesos, marathon, dcos

I have dcos up and running. I created a service and i am able to access it through the ip:port   but when i try to do the same with marathon-lb i just cant reach it. I tried curl http://marathon-lb.marathon.mesos:10000/   10000 being the port number, i still get connection refused.

Here is my json for service:

```
{


"id": "/nginx-external",
  "cmd": null,
  "cpus": 0.1,
  "mem": 65,
  "disk": 0,
  "instances": 1,
  "acceptedResourceRoles": [],
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "volumes": [],
    "docker": {
      "image": "nginx:1.7.7",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 2000,
          "servicePort": 10000,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "labels": {}
        }
      ],
      "privileged": false,
      "parameters": [],
      "forcePullImage": true
    }
  },
  "healthChecks": [
    {
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 10,
      "intervalSeconds": 2,
      "timeoutSeconds": 10,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 10,
      "portIndex": 0,
      "path": "/",
      "protocol": "HTTP",
      "ignoreHttp1xx": false
    }
  ],
  "labels": {
    "HAPROXY_GROUP": "external"
  },
  "portDefinitions": [
    {
      "port": 10000,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "name": "default",
      "labels": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both accessing it from outside the cluster by using `public-ip:10000` (see [here](https://dcos.io/docs/1.10/administering-clusters/locate-public-agent/) for finding the public ip) and from inside the cluster using `curl  http://marathon-lb.marathon.mesos:10000/` worked fine. Note, you need to have marathon-lb installed (`dcos package install marathon-lb`) and `marathon-lb.marathon.mesos` can only be resolved from inside the cluster.

In order to debug marathon-lb issues I ususally check the haproxy stats first: https://dcos.io/docs/1.9/networking/marathon-lb/marathon-lb-advanced-tutorial/#deploy-an-external-load-balancer-with-marathon-lb

**From outside the cluster**
 [image: external access]

**From inside the cluster**

```
    core@ip-10-0-4-343 ~ $ curl  http://marathon-lb.marathon.mesos:10000/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot js84, this actually helped solve the issue. Thanks for explaining.